# Can't remove LocalStorage Item with .removeItem

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to remove a localStorage with .removeItem(keys) but it's said the localStorage keys is not defined. I'm trying to make a simple localStorage again like below, and then trying to removeItem again, still the same problem. What's wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        localStorage.test = "good";
        console.log(localStorage.test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
    </script>
</head>
```

The browser said, "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined". I'm trying using window.localStorage.clear(), it's work, but I want to specify which localStorage I want to delete.

Comment: Just remove it with quotes like `localStorage.removeItem("test");` also check https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Oh, It's work, it's help me, thanks Hakan Kose

Comment: Errors like this are a good reason to learn about and get into the habit of using [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) JavaScript (specially browser implementations of JavaScript) have some wild methods of resolving global variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you are running into an error is because, `test` is not available in the scope of code ( and a reference error is thrown, when you try to access a variable that is not defined yet). In your case it lives on `localStorage.test` because you are attaching it directly to `localStorage` object.

If you had used `localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.test);` instead, you would not have come across the error.

And it is not a good idea to set properties on the `localStorage` object directly.
Instead use `setItem` to store data in local storage.

```
var value = "good";

localStorage.setItem('test', value); // set the item

console.log(localStorage.getItem('test')); // retrieve the item

localStorage.removeItem('test');  // delete the item
```

In `setItem`, `getItem` and `removeItem` the first argument is the `key` that you want to store or retrieve or delete from the storage. The name of the key in this case is `test`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's help me a lot :)